# when i use command `mvn test -Xlint:unchecked` . some error appear

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'lint' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from
 the repositories [local (C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository), alimaven (http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'lint' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org
.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository), alimaven (http://maven.aliyu
n.com/nexus/content/groups/public/)]
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:93)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:
103)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:
83)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like your question is similar with [Trouble with -Xlint:all and maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369505/trouble-with-xlintall-and-maven)
or even
[How to compile using -Xlint:unchecked in a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449251/how-to-compile-using-xlintunchecked-in-a-maven-project)

Just add

```
<compilerArguments>
    <Xlint:unchecked />
</compilerArguments>
```

or

```
<compilerArguments>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArguments>
```

to your maven-compiler-plugin configuration

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the option is not working anymore

```
<compilerArguments> <Xlint:unchecked /> </compilerArguments>
```

So, to solve my problem, i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530284/org-codehaus-plexus-archiver-jar-jararchiver-unsupported-major-minor-version-49) this solution and change my plugin compiler

from

```
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
```

to

```
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
```

Then my plugin looks like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>        
</plugin>
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way, but works fine for me.